# Reactjs Script to implement like utterances with tagging like Dialog flow

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I want to implement tagging of few text strings inside a sentence that opens a popout to tag to something.
Example of Dialog flow :
[image]

Here when i select the word "tomorrow" it opens a popout window and it allows to tag it to link it to the entity sys.date similarly selection of string "at 5pm" links to @sys.time

Comment: Are you integrating Dialogflow with Kommunicate?

Comment: No i am no. This is what i m trying to implement very similar to dialog flow